# python number generator possible infinite loop

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

I looked through several similar questions on here but none of them solved my problem and, in addition, I'm not 100% sure what my problem is.

Anyway, I'm trying to generate a list in python containing 9 lists with 9 elements each. Since this list is for a sudoku generator the lists need to conform to the rules of a sudoku puzzle.
This is what I tried to do:

```
def generateBord (mtx) : 

    while (len(mtx) < 9) and (len(mtx) != 9):
        newrow = generateRow(mtx)
        mtx.append(newrow)

    return mtx

def generateRow (mtx):
    counter = 0
    row = []
    while counter < 9:

        num = random.randint(1,9)
        idx = len(row)

        if (not(num in row)):
            for x in mtx:
                if (num != x[idx]):
                    row.append(num)
                    counter += 1

    if (len(row) == 9):
        return row
```

When I try to run the code, it never terminates, so I think the problem is an infinite loop somewhere. By trial and error I narrowed the problem down to this bit:

```
for x in mtx:
    if (num != x[idx]):
        row.append(num)
        counter += 1
```

However, I'm not quite sure what the problem is exactly. When calling the function generateBord(mtx), I give it

```
 mtx = []
```

as an argument. 
I hope this isn't too vague. What is the problem here exactly and how do I fix it? Or is my approach not viable at all?

Comment: There are some redundant tests here, and the logic in `generateRow` seems seriously flawed.  You're also not checking to see that there are no duplicates in any of the nine 3x3 squares.

Comment: @TomKarzes I'm aware about the 3x3 squares, I didn't add that yet since I figured that the problem was somewhere in the for-loop and wanted to solve that first before making it more "complicated".
Would you mind elaborating on what tests are redundant and how you would improve the logic of generateRow?

Comment: I suspect that generating valid sudoku boards is massively harder than solving the resulting puzzle

Comment: For redundant tests, here's an example:  `x < 9 and x != 9` is equivalent to just `x < 9`.  The first condition implies the second.

Comment: The culprit = *`for x in mtx:`*. `mtx` is **empty**, therefore `counter += 1` never incremented, therfore `while counter < 9:` always `True` == **infinite loop**.